# Gnuplot 5.0.0 3D splot maps or Labelled multiplots

Tags: gnuplot, label

I am having issues with gnuplot 5.0.0 and I would like to know:

Is there a known issue with Gnuplot or just Gnuplot 5.0.0, that prevents the generation of labels on splot plots?

As, (1)

```
set label 1 '0.0007Vnm' @POS
splot 'FullData/All_5.0GHz_0.0007Vnm_l50ns_GCND.dat' matrix lc rgb "#000000" title "Test"
```

generates the FEM Heat Map as desired, but... (2)

```
set label 1 '0.007Vnm' @POS
plot 'FullData/All_5.0GHz_0.007Vnm_l50ns_GCND.dat' matrix lc rgb "#000000" title "0.007Vnm"
```

Generates a blank, but labelled plot.

**Comparison image shown here, Top left = (1), Top right = (2)**

[image: Comparison image shown here, Top left = (1), Top right = (2)]

Answer (score 0):

In the `splot` case, adding the `front` keyword might work:

```
set label 1 '0.0007Vnm' @POS front
```

Comment: I just tried that, and it didn't work.

However, if I open the .eps file that is generated in Adobe Illustrator, I can see the labels I want, are no where near the plots.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

plotting "at graph x,y" makes the x and y co-ordinates [0:1], so they must be plotted within that range.

Plotting "at x,y" uses the actual graph co-ordinates for label plotting.